# Trying to rewrite realloc function in c

Tags: c

As practice, I'm trying to rewrite realloc function

```
void updateSize(void* p,int length)
{
    free(p);
    malloc(sizeof(p) * length);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int *y =malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    y = updateSize(y, 5);
}
```

But when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
void value not ignored as it ought to be.
```

What is the reason for this error, and how can i fix it?

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: `updateSize` doesn't return a thing (**void**), why do you assign it to `y`? The error message is very informative.

Comment: @KerrekSB at this line: int *y =malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

Comment: 1: realloc is much smarter than this (and in many cases will be a no-op), 2: you aren't using malloc correctly at all in your function, 3: at a minimum, your function must take a double pointer or return a pointer so that the new memory location is known to the main program, 4: you need to be able to copy the old memory

Comment: It should be clear that realloc can not possibly work this way.

Comment: The size you reallocate is wrong, unless your intention is to specify a number of pointers to make space for.

Comment: ... and you have data loss. `realloc` is supposed to keep the maximal contents of the original object, you are throwing all that away.

Answer (score 1):

OP is not returning a value from function nor copying data as needed.

```
// Function return value of `void` needs to be `void *`.
// `length` should be of type size_t
// The former length of `p` needs to be passed.
// Potential NULL pointers need testing.
void updateSize(void* p,int length) {
  // Missing data copy.
  // Allocate new memory and copy before freeing old
  free(p);
  // Returned value from malloc needs saving.
  // No reason for 'sizeof()'
  malloc(sizeof(p) * length);
}

// Recommend
void *updateSize2(void* p, size_t OldLength, size_t NewLength) {
  void *p2 = malloc(NewLength);
  if (p && p2) {
    memcpy(p2, p, OldLength < NewLength ? OldLength : NewLength);
  }
  if (p2 || (NewLength == 0)) {
    free(p);  // Note A
  }
  return p2;
}
```

---

Note A: There is an interesting issue when `NewLength == 0`.  Some `malloc(0)` implementations return NULL, others return a pointer to "no data".  In the former, a NULL pointer does not *always* imply a failed `malloc()`.  Now as @sharth rightly points out that `free(p)` should only be called on memory allocation failure, the `if()` used here is conditional on `NewLength`.

Comment: You should only `free(p)` when `p2 != NULL`.

Comment: @sharth Your comment to only free `p2 != NULL` is a good idea and consistent with `realloc()` functionality; thank-you.  Answer amended.